# How do I store data from a file into different arrays? C language

Tags: arrays, c, file

For a program where we calculate student grade and print out the result, I am facing a problem.
We have to take data from a .dat file using fscanf, fopen etc etc.

The problem is, the data is in this format:

"Student name" "student ID" "student answers"

such as:

john 4834HUF A C D B C

Paul 579GYF C B B D A
(answers are of an mcq, so the answers are A,B,C or D)

So I guess I'll have to have different arrays to store the name and ID and Answers. Now how do I make sure "John" gets into the name array, "483HUF" goes to the ID array and "A C D B C" gets into the answers array.
EDIT: I guess I'll have to create 10 arrays for 10 mcq answers so that I can compare with correct answer.

Comment: Why different arrays? Why not create a `struct` to hold Student information and create an array of those?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are asking. Are you struggling with separating the lines of your file? Are you struggling to assign different values to different arrays? Please be more precise about your problem. Also please update your question to show your current effort.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre].

Comment: How do you get to create 10 arrays? You have 5 answers per line in your sample context

Comment: struct wasn't taught to us but okay i guess i'll use it. The .dat file is non-negotiable though, so can I import the data from the file using struct?

Comment: The type for storing your content within your program is not strictly related to the way you store your content in the file. It's main job of your program to convert accordingly while reading from your file.

Comment: @Gerhardh ignore the number of answers, just gave an example. In the actual project, i have 20 answers per person. I'll make it correct in the actual code ofc.

Comment: Divide your large and complex assignment into smaller and simpler parts. Continue to sub-divide each and every part until none can be divided any more. The solves the now very small and very simple problems, one by one, and put them together to finally solve the original problem.

Comment: For a start try to read each line into single variables. Then if that works, think about storing them into an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use arrays but you will have to make separate arrays for each attribute.

Better way to store would be to use a `struct` array to store your data. Doc : [C Struct](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm)

Your struct may look like this:

```
typedef struct student{
   char  studentName[20];
   char  studentID[20];
   char  *answers[20]; //because this will a array of strings, assuming there will be maximum 20 MCQ's eg. {'A', 'B', 'C' ..}
}student;
```

If you would like to store answers as "ABC.."
then

```
typedef struct student{
   char  studentName[20];
   char  studentID[20];
   char  answers[20]; 
}student;
```

```
student data[10]; //struct array, with max students = 10
```

After scrapping each line on .dat file, you could store the first student as follow:

```
strcpy(data[0].studentName, name); //assuming name is the variable for scraped name in the line
strcpy(data[0].studentID, ID); //assuming ID is the variable for scraped ID in the line
strcpy(data[0].answers, answers); //assuming answers = "ABC.."
```